# Split code to separate node js files or modules in Node.js bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am building a chatbot application using the MS bot framework. I have two flows, they are flow1 and flow2. All the code is placed in app.js. I want to split it into different files: app.js, flow1.js & flow2.js and I want to use flow1.js and flow2.js functions in app.js.

Below is the app.js code

```
bot.dialog('Flow', [
    function(session, results) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Please select the flow', 'flow1|flow2', { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
    },function (session, results) {
        if(results.response.entity === 'flow1'){
            session.beginDialog('Flow1')
        }else{
            session.beginDialog('Flow2')
        }
    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);

bot.dialog('Flow1', [
    function(session, results) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "May I know your name?")
    },function (session, results) {
        session.userData.name = results.response
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Hi! What is your favorite color?")
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.userData.color = results.response.entity
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please enter color code?")
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.userData.colorcode = results.response
        session.send('Your inputs <br>name: '+session.userData.name+
                    "<br>color: "+session.userData.color+
                    "<br>color code : "+session.userData.colorcode);
        session.endConversation();
    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);

bot.dialog('Flow2', [
    function(session, results) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please enter your user name?")
    },function (session, results) {
        session.userData.username = results.response
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please enter your password?")
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.userData.password = results.response
        session.userData.colorcode = results.response
        session.send('Your inputs <br>username: '+session.userData.username+
                    "<br>Password: "+session.userData.password);
        session.endConversation();
    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: I am the beginner for node js. I dont know how to do this